# JetBrains IDE color scheme gallery

Tags: themes, jetbrains-ide

In current IDE instances of JetBrains we have default white theme, and the 2nd dark theme.

I would love to have more editor color theme though my google search shows little helpful result i.e. only some JetBrains plugins.

I think we can customize the syntax color theme and export to files to apply to another machine - there should be a gallery for that.

So if you know any JetBrains IDE color scheme gallery, please share.
Thank you.

Comment: It must depends on IDE -- PhpStorm has more than 3 bundled themes. In any case: http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/ or https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/tree/master/jetbrains ... but you have to check if they are up to date .. as new styling elements can be added in any version and such downloaded theme may became outdated. Plus, it may not contain colors for specific language (e.g. may only cover only basic set etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting `Ctrol-Backquote` and choose `Color Scheme` will list some syntax highlight scheme/skin options.

[image]

[image]